# Is complimentary Wi-Fi available on ICE trains outside of Germany?

Tags: trains, public-transport, internet, wifi, deutsche-bahn

As [this new answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/89093/32134) correctly states

> Since 1 January 2017 there is Wi-Fi in all ICE-Trains.

What about the international ICE connections, is Wi-Fi available there as well? E.g. on the ICE from Frankfurt to Paris Est or the ICE from Hamburg/Dortmund to Vienna.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit:
**Yes**, as of this week I did have internet access through the on-board Wi-Fi on an ICE train while in France. The connection quality was not great, but neither was reception on my phone at the same time.

Old answer:
No, as of today no Wi-Fi/Internet is available yet on the parts of the journey of these trains that are outside of Germany.

Sources:

- personal experience
- DB support confirmed via Twitter, but added that the service shall be extended to some international connections this year. No more info was available

Comment: By *extra-German parts*, I take it you mean the parts outside Germany, rather than the parts that are really, really German?  (Not a serious question, I just loved the image of extremely-German trains.  Amazingly on-time, or something like that.)  +1 from me, anyway.

Comment: According to that definition, there are a few extra-German ICEs, but you won't know in advance. :-)

Comment: @MadHatter - You mean Swiss trains, I think.

Comment: @simonatrcl I agree those run on time, but in my experience the Germans are pretty good at organising important national infrastructure as well.  Certainly better than my own dear home clusterfark; how I miss British Rail.